# How can I have threadsafe instance variables within Inlinescript block when using Powershell workflows?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm using PowerShell 3 and playing with Workflows and I have run across something curious.
I am using an **inlinescript** block hold some code to represent a task that I want to run many instances of.  What I have found is that variables declared within this **inlinescript** block can be accessed across parallel instances.

My sample here has the parallel process sleep for a random number of milliseconds but you can see from the console output that multiple concurrent processes may sleep for the same number of milliseconds.  Sure, this is possible, but it's so often that it's clear the data is not threadsafe.

```
workflow Invoke-ForEachParallel
{
    param([string[]]$Computers)
    foreach -parallel($PC in $Computers)
    {
        inlinescript {
            "Executing on $using:PC"
            [int]$i = get-random -min 200 -max 3000
            "`t$using:PC - Sleeping for $i milliseconds."
            start-sleep -Milliseconds $i
            "`tFinished processing on $using:PC"
        }
    }
}  

cls
Invoke-ForEachParallel (1..50)
```

So, the question is: how can I get ensure that each concurrent process is working with its own variable instances?

Comment: OK, this is super sad.  I'm working around workflow by using the technique described in this blog.  I'd really like to fix this workflow issue, though.  http://powertoe.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/foreach-parallel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Wyatt answered both simply and in detail on this thread.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/155b5638-5477-4e7c-a154-c6b56f6c3145/how-can-i-have-threadsafe-instance-variables-within-inlinescript-block-when-using-powershell?prof=required

Simple answer:
When you use inlineScript, it's not a multi-threaded scenario; it's multi-process.  Workflow Foundation starts up a new powershell.exe process to execute the code in the inlineScript block each time through (you can see this happening in Task Manager while running your script).  There is no way for there to be thread-safety issues between separate processes (unless you have the Debug Programs right and use WriteProcessMemory for some silly reason).

Edit:  On my Windows 7 system, the number of PowerShell.exe processes spawned in this script seems to be limited to 5.  I'm not sure if WF tears down and restarts these processes for each execution of the inlineScript block, or if it treats them as a pool, reusing them until everything's done.  I would assume the latter, for performance reasons, but I don't haven't read any MS documentation to that effect.